# Yet another Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I've been looking through SO and I can't quite find a solution.

I have a React project in a folder called "client" on port 3000 and an express app in a folder called "server" on port 5000. I initiate both projects using docker.

I have a Login component (login.component.js):

```
import AuthService from '../services/auth.service';

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            username: "", 
            password: "",
            loading: false
        };
    }

    handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            password: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { history } = this.props;

        AuthService.userLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password)
        .then(() => {
            history.push("/user");
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-app">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin} className="login-form">
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="email" 
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.username}
                        onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} />
                    </div>
                   
                    <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input 
                        type="password" 
                        name="password" 
                        className="form-control" 
                        value={this.state.password}
                        onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary w-100">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

And the service file (auth.service.js):

```
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import axios from "axios";
require('dotenv').config();

const cookies = new Cookies();

class AuthService {
    userLogin(username, password) {
        return axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE + '/login', 
        { 
            username: username, 
            password: password

        }).then((res) => {
            if(res.data.access_token) {
                
                cookies.set("userToken", JSON.stringify(res.data.access_token), { path: "/" });
            }
            return res.data;
        });
    }
}

export default new AuthService();
```

where process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE=http://localhost:5000. In my "server" folder I have app.js (first 30 lines):

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var axios = require('axios');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var authRouter = require('./routes/auth');
var userRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// routes
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/login', authRouter);
app.use('/user', userRouter);
```

The routes and controllers send an axios request to my API url, where it does return a token (200 status) that I can use to grab user data. However, from my Login component I receive an error after pressing submit:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.
▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/app/src/components/login.component.js:36
  33 | 
  34 |     AuthService.userLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password)
  35 |     .then(() => {
> 36 |         history.push("/user");
  37 |         window.location.reload();
  38 |     });
  39 | }
```

I'm a new developer. My index.js file includes . I can't understand why this is happening. Printing from the React UI does return a valid token so I know it's communicating with the backend, but the UI seems to have the issue.

I have tried to use "Redirect" from the react-router-dom documentation just to see if I'm using "history.push()" incorrectly, but now I'm confused if it's a CORS issue (the console says Uncaught in promise as well). Any help would be appreciated.